# C# multithreading return

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am not familiar with multithreading. Image I have a method to do some intensive search on a string, and return 2 lists of integers as out parameters.

```
public static void CalcModel(string s, out List<int> startPos, out List<int> len)
    {
        // Do some intensive search
    }
```

The search on long string is very time consuming. So I want to split the string into several fragments, search with multithreads, and recombine the result (adjust the startPos accordingly).

How to integrate multithreading in this kinda process? Thanks

I forgot to mention the following two things:

1. I want to set a string length cutoff, and let the code to decide how many fragments it needs.
2. I had a hard time to associate the startPos of each fragments (on the original string) with the thread. How can I do that?

Comment: [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) might work here.

Comment: Um, you sort of gave the answer in your question. You split the string into fragments, hand each fragment to a different thread, then recombine the results.

Comment: I would change my solution a little bit. I'd create a class `SearchResult` (or whatever) with the following properties: `String`, `StartingIndex`, `StartPosition` and `Length`. Each thread would receive an object of this type and return it with `StartPosition` and `Length` fulfilled. What do you think about it?

Comment: To fill the lists you can give each thread its own list and merge in the end, or you could use a concurrent collection.

Comment: @RaymondChen Agreed, I think this user just wants some sample code to get them pointed in the right direction :)  I'm wagering the user is doing a bit more than just a regex.  But I can't be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than get too bogged down in details, generally, you send each thread a "return object."   Once you've started all the threads, you block on them and wait until they are all finished.

While each thread is running, the thread modifies its work object and terminates when it has produced the output.

So roughly this (I can't tell exactly how you want to split it up, so perhaps you can modify this):

```
public class WorkItem {
    public string InputString;
    public List<int> startPos;
    public List<int> len;
}

public static void CalcLotsOfStrings(string s, out List<int> startPos, out List<int> len)
{
    WorkItem wi1 = new WorkItem();
    wi1.InputString = s;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(InternalCalcThread1);
    t1.Start(wi1);
    WorkItem wi2 = new WorkItem();
    wi2.InputString = s;
    Thread t2 = new Thread(InternalCalcThread2);
    t2.Start(wi2);

    // You can now wait for the threads to complete or start new threads
    // When you're done, wi1 and wi2 will be filled with the updated data
    // but make sure not to use them until the threads are done!
}


public static void InternalCalcThread1(object item)
{
    WorkItem w = item as WorkItem;
    w.startPos = new List<int>();
    w.len = new List<int>();

    // Do work here - populate the work item data
}


public static void InternalCalcThread2(object item)
{
    // Do work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I am not sure about the performance on these methods

```
Parallel.Invoke(
           () => CalcModel(s,startPos, len), 
           () => CalcModel(s,startPos, len)
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

To create and run multiple threads is a very easy task. All you need is method which acts as a starting point for a thread.

Suppose you have the `CalcModel` method as defined in your original post then you only have to do:

```
// instantiate the thread with a method as starting point
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CalcModel));

// run the thread
t.Start();
```

However if you want the thread to return some values you might apply a little trick because you can't return values directly like you do it with a `return` statement or `out` parameters.

You can 'wrap' the thread in its own class and let him store its data in the class's fields:

```
public class ThreadClass {

    public string FieldA;
    public string FieldB;
    //...

    public static void Run () {

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_run));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void _run() {

        //...
        fieldA = "someData";
        fieldB = "otherData"
        //...
    }
}
```

That's only a very rough example to illustrate the idea. I doesn't include any parts for thread synchronization or thread control.

I would say the more difficult task would be to think about splitting your `CalcModel` method in a way that it can be parallelized and then maybe more important how the partially results can be joined together to form one single end solution.